# using java to copy files makes an unwanted copy under tomcat installation directory

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

In my web-application , I am using java to copy files from one computer to an other computer. it is working fine but I get extra copy of every file under tomcat installation directory. It seems that java is using tomcat directory as a temp folder to move files from one place to an other place and never clean up it's mess.
How can I avoid this type of behavior?

Here is my copy function

```
private static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File targetDir) throws IOException, FileAlreadyExistsException {

        File destFile = new File(targetDir, sourceFile.getName());

        if(destFile.exists()) {
            throw new FileAlreadyExistsException(destFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            if(!targetDir.exists()){
                targetDir.mkdirs();
            }
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;

        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        }
        finally {
            if(source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if(destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I am using `renameTo` to move files.

Comment: What code are you using to perform the copying?

Comment: I have updated my question with related source code

Comment: Not related to your question, but you could use the return value of `createNewFile()` to check, if the file already exists. This avoids race conditions.

Comment: Please also provide sample data for the method arguments and check, if this method works fine without a tomcat (e.g. by creating a unit test) to verify your theory, that it is a tomcat related problem.

Comment: "I am using `renameTo` to move files". Is that related to the copy operation? Something you do before/after you copy? Or is it an unrelated comment?

Comment: @ RealSkepticI have two method , one for copy and the other for moving files. I have copied the function for copy. I use simple renameTo function for implementing my move function. peoblem happens in both of them.

Comment: And where are the files coming from? Those file operations are local, and you say that the files come from different computers. Are they mounted remotely or how?

Comment: I highly suspect that the problem is in the surrounding code, and not in this copy function. Are you sure you are calling it only once per file-copy operation? How do you get hold of your File instances?